# Redirect to another URL and back for Certifcate base Login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ssl, cloud-foundry

Currently i developing an application which have two routes which are in different domain.

Example :

Route 1: https://test.apps.com

Route 2: https://test.cert-apps.com

Users uses Route 1 to access the application. In the Login page there is an option for Certificate based login . But certificate based authentication is only enabled in route 2.

So how do i do the certificate based authentication by redirecting from Route 1 to Route 2 and once client is authenticated redirect to route 1.

Following are the code that i currently using which are not working:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginContr {

    @RequestMapping("/certificate")
    public String message(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
              sendGET();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "login";
    }
   @RequestMapping("/extractcertificate")
    private String extractEmailFromCertificate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String email = "";
        //Code to extract email from certificate
        return email;
    }
private static void sendGET() throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL("https://test.cert-apps.com/login/extractcertificate");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("GET request not worked");
    }

}

}
```

The above code gives the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

sendGet() method sends a request to Route 2 and calls `/extractcertificate` webservice to do certificate based authentication and once its done it will retrive the email address.

Technology using for app: Java,Spring,Angualar 4, Cloud Foundary

Is there any alternative to do this or any inbuilt implementation , any tips would be great advantage..

Comment: It looks like you're client keystore is missing the certificate either for `test.cert-apps.com` or for `test.apps.com` have you installed both in the keystore as trusted?  Is the keystore being used?

Comment: Certificate-based authentication requires the client to talk directly to the server because the TLS cert of the client is presented in the TLS handshake.  This does not happen by default on CF, but there are a couple ways to make this happen.  Can you clarify?  1.) Where is TLS being terminated in your CF environment?  2.) Are you using TCP routes?  3.) Are you using this feature of CF -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#forward-client-cert?